# this cod show all array list i want to show first row in array list and then click button show row number two

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter

this cod show all array list i want to show first row in array list and then click button show row number two  and click again show row number three and then can do that

public void onClick(View v) {
                        babyViewModel.getLetterRecourceID();

this cod show all array list i want to show first row in array list and then click button show row number two  and click again show row number three and then can do that

the cod in activity_englishletters the first code

```
activity_englishletters
package com.example.learnn;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.learnn.databinding.ActivityEnglishcolorsBinding;
import com.example.learnn.databinding.ActivityEnglishlettersBinding;
import com.example.learnn.ui.BabyListAdapter;
import com.example.learnn.ui.BabyModel;
import com.example.learnn.ui.BabyViewModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EnglishlettersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BabyViewModel babyViewModel;
    ImageView imagee,next;
    RecyclerView recycler;
    private int index = 0;
    ArrayList arrayList,letterList;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityEnglishlettersBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_englishletters);

        imagee = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagee);
        recycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);

        final BabyListAdapter adapter = new BabyListAdapter();
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        babyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BabyViewModel.class);
        babyViewModel.letterRecourceIDMutableLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<BabyModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<BabyModel> babyModels) {
                adapter.setList(babyModels);
            }
        });

        binding.next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                babyViewModel.getLetterRecourceID();
                index = index+1;
                if (index < letterList.size()) {
                    imagee.setBackgroundResource( (int) letterList.get( index  ) );
                    return;
                }

                if (index == letterList.size()) {
                    imagee.setBackgroundResource( (int) letterList.get( 0 ) );
                    index = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }


}


viewModel

package com.example.learnn.ui;

import com.example.learnn.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class BabyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    ArrayList arrayList;

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<BabyModel>> letterRecourceIDMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();


    public void getLetterRecourceID(){
        letterRecourceIDMutableLiveData.setValue(getDataFromDatabase());
     }

     private ArrayList<BabyModel> getDataFromDatabase(){
        ArrayList<BabyModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
         arrayList.add(new BabyModel(R.drawable.a));
         arrayList.add(new BabyModel(R.drawable.b));
         arrayList.add(new BabyModel(R.drawable.c));
         arrayList.add(new BabyModel(R.drawable.d));
         arrayList.add(new BabyModel(R.drawable.e));
         return arrayList;
    }
}

adapter

package com.example.learnn.ui;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.learnn.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class BabyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BabyListAdapter.BabyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<BabyModel> letterList = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BabyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new BabyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.litter_list_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BabyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.image.setImageResource(letterList.get(position).getLetterRecourceID());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return letterList.size();
    }


    public void setList(ArrayList<BabyModel> letterList) {
        this.letterList = letterList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class BabyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        public BabyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagee);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you point to which line is the app crashing?

Comment: if (index < letterList.size()) {

Comment: babyViewModel.letterRecourceIDMutableLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<BabyModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<BabyModel> babyModels) {
                adapter.setList(babyModels);
            }
        });
This is most probably babyModels is null
So when you are clicking the button--> it is crashing

Comment: i solve it change if (index < letterList.size()) { to if (index < ((letterList == null) ? 0 : letterList.size())) {

Comment: i want to set one image  a  from araay list when click button then click again set b and then click again set c    but now sho all aray list hwo to solve this problem

Comment: yes this way you are checking more null before accessing the list

Comment: I didn't get your problem at all

Comment: this cod show all array list                                                                                                   binding.next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                babyViewModel.getLetterRecourceID();                                                              i want to show one row and click button again show next row ho do that

Comment: well you can do by showing only part of the list. For example you can do a sublist and on click of the button add a new list to the adapter (update)

Comment: can write code please

Answer (score 1):

[image]So, as a starter you will have a global index

```
int index=0;
```

then on the button click:

```
babyViewModel.letterRecourceIDMutableLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<BabyModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<BabyModel> babyModels) {
            List<BabyModel> list = babyModels.subList(0, index);
            adapter.setList(list);
            index++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: give me error in (list) because it array list not list

Comment: then make arrayList a List

Comment: then make arrayList a List  can cod please

Comment: it already make in this code up                                                                                                                                                                            
    public void setList(ArrayList<BabyModel> letterList) {
        this.letterList = letterList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I am sorry but I really have absolutely no idea what you are saying.

Comment: can see picture

Comment: public void onChanged(List<BabyModel> babyModels) {